# RP3 isn't working after months of not using it

Tags: hardware

So, I haven't used my RP3 for months because I was busy with other things to do like school and exams. Now when I took out my RP3 and plugged it into a power supply, I noticed the power goes off after a few seconds and the sd card usage blinks, goes dim, bright or turns off randomly. At the same time, the CPU overheats like balls. No joke like 90 degrees or over in just a few seconds.

Even after removing the sd card, this time the power light remains on but the CPU still overheats like hell but takes a bit longer.

Is this a hardware or software issue? I got my RP3 like 3/4 a year ago on Amazon. Is there a warranty for these sort of stuff?

Comment: Was the pi stored in a case or just a bare pi board? Have you inspected the pi visually? Any bent pins, damage to the board etc.

Comment: Hm. I stored it bare board. I think that could be why. It was full of dust which I brushed off. But I didn't see any damage to it at all.

Answer (score 0):

In general - the RED LED is connected to +5V and activated by signal from CPU.
The +5V is a product of regulators and the actual regulator hardware depends on RPi model.

Power regulators technology has been around for few years and MOST of them are thermo protected.

In short - looks as you power source is WAY off the nominal 5.1V and is shutting down. 
TRY To locate the actual regulator (on RPI 3) , not CPU and see how hot it gets.

**BETTER YET CHECK YOUR POWER SOURCE FIRST!**

https://www.raspberrypi.org/app/uploads/2012/04/Raspberry-Pi-Schematics-R1.0.pdf

Comment: Well I tried multiple power sources, like a battery bank (2 out of 4 LEDs on power indicator), my laptop, two mobile chargers (OnePlus 3 and Samsung) but got the same result. Can you tell me where this regulator is located?

Comment: Hello, so I did some more tests and it turns out that the RP3 works! When I plugged it into the T.V. there is output, it works perfectly fine except for the CPU overheating like hell in a few seconds because of which it continuously reboots until it just completely turns off. Do you know why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

The CPU getting hot very fast is a symptom of the Pi being dead.

A Pi death is often caused by an over voltage - either more than 5V supplied as power, or more than 3V3 supplied to a GPIO.

Any warranty will depend on your jurisdiction.

Comment: Hello, so I did some more tests and it turns out that the RP3 works! When I plugged it into the T.V. there is output, it works perfectly fine except for the CPU overheating like hell in a few seconds because of which it continuously reboots until it just completely turns off. Do you know why this could be happening?

Comment: I think the term to look up is thermal runaway.  The damage done to one part of the chip gradually spreads through all the chip.